# How to display data from a JSON variable in 3 columns into bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, nested-loops

I have loaded a JSON data into my HTML page using JQuery and if I click a button in the HTML page, I have managed to pop-up a bootstrap modal that displays the content of the JSON variable.

However, the display of the JSON data is not always working. I want the data to be displayed in 3 columns, and so the data gets displayed only when the number of elements in the JSON array is divisible by 3 (i.e. say JSON array contains 108 elements, the modal displays the list of JSON data in 3 columns but the modal doesn't display the list when the JSON array contains say 109/110 elements)

Sample Content of JSON -

```
{"id": "NP", "name": "Nepal", "z": 1, "percent": 0.01, "ips": ["190.123.21.5"]}, {"id": "MC", "name": "Monaco", "z": 1, "percent": 0.01, "ips": ["88.209.114.156"]},{...},...]
```

The following is the source code I have written-

```
var data;
$.getJSON( "data1105.json", function( json ) {
    data = json
});

function renderModalBody() {
    var modalentries = '';
    var i;
    var j;
    var rank;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 3) {
        modalentries += '<tr>';
        for (j = i; j <= i + 2; j++) {
            rank = j + 1
            modalentries += '<td>' + rank + '. ' + data[j].name + ' (' + data[j].z + ') </td>'
        }
        modalentries += '</tr>'
    }
    $('#nodedetails').html(modalentries)
}
```

The way I want the bootstrap modal to display content is as-

```
1. United States (2500)    2. New Zealand (1500)    3. China (1400)
4. France (600)            5. Germany (515)         6. Romania (320)
6. ...                     7. ....                  8. ...
   ................................................................
   ................................................................
106. ...                  107. ...                 108. ...
109. ...                  110. ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you have a number of data values which is not divisible by 3 your inner `for` loop runs beyond the valid `data` values and causes an `undefined index` error. You can work around that by limiting `j` to `data.length-1` as well as `i+2`, and then adding a second inner `for` loop to output empty `td`s to make up the rest of the row:

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": "NP",
    "name": "Nepal",
    "z": 1,
    "percent": 0.01,
    "ips": ["190.123.21.5"]
  },
  {
    "id": "MC",
    "name": "Monaco",
    "z": 1,
    "percent": 0.01,
    "ips": ["88.209.114.156"]
  }
];

function renderModalBody() {
  var modalentries = '';
  var i;
  var j;
  var rank;
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i = i + 3) {
    modalentries += '<tr>';
    for (j = i; j <= i + 2 && j < data.length; j++) {
      rank = j + 1
      modalentries += '<td>' + rank + '. ' + data[j].name + ' (' + data[j].z + ') </td>'
    }
    for (; j <= i + 2; j++) {
      modalentries += '<td></td>'
    }
    modalentries += '</tr>'
  }
  $('#nodedetails').html(modalentries)
}

renderModalBody();
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="nodedetails"></table>
```